# If a sequence converges to 0 in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a function is 0 at every point of the sequence and at 0, is 0 an eigenvalue of the Jacobian?

Tags: real-analysis

The function is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have thought about possibly picking a subsequence which converges to 0 from a single direction, then taking the directional derivative, but I don't think this subsequence exists.

Comment: You need to know that the sequence (lets call it $(x_n)_n$) is different from $0$, i.e., $x_n \neq 0$. Then, consider $(x_n / |x_n|)_n$. What can you say about this sequence? Also, you need to assume a priori that your function (say, $f$) is differentiable.

Comment: What are the hypotheses on $f?$ Differentiable, $C^1, ...$? Also, don't you want to rule out the sequence $0,0,\dots$?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that the sequence is infinite. The motivation for this is showing that a continuously differentiable vector field with infinite singularities on the disk has a degenerate singularity. I am now certain that the subsequence I mentioned in the question exists, I just don't know why. It is easy to think of a sequence that converges to 0 for example, but doesn't have a subsequence which converges from a single direction. For example, take the orbit of an irrational rotation on the circle and shrink it to zero as time goes to infinity.